# RSA parameter generator algorithm

Tags: rsa

i'm studying for my basic crypto class and I'm trying to formalize the algorithm for the parameter generation of RSA, unfortunately, I cannot find any algorithm, just plain text.

Can someone tell me if this algorithm could be accepted? Please focus more on the public exponent $e$

1. KeyGen()

   2. Let $p,q$ be two random prime numbers
   3. $N\leftarrow pq$
   4. $\phi(N)=(p-1)(q-1)$
   5. $e\xleftarrow{R}\{x|\;0< x < \phi(N) \land x\in \mathbb{N} \land gcd(x,\phi(N))=1 \}$ // $\xleftarrow{R}$ means that the element is chosen randomly
   6. calculate $d$ such that $ed\equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(N)}$
   7. $PK\leftarrow (N,e)$
   8. $SK\leftarrow (N,d)$
   9. return $(pk,sk)$

Comment: Ideally the $e$ is selected on advance, when $\gcd(e,\phi(n))\neq 1$ we select new randoms.  The key-gen should take a security parameter like $1^{2048}$ to determine the modulus size...

Comment: yup i got it but i would like to avoid the while loop as hell, just to make the code clean.

Said that the definition of the set Is correct?

Comment: What about the [Wikipedia's RSA Key-gen?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation). Yours almost sound like it! And, **could be accepted for what?**

Comment: omg thank you, i don't know how but I missed it.

By accepted I mean that could be okay to write that code in a basic crypto class exam (of course followed by a more verbal explanation)

Comment: Interesting that a crypto class doesn't mention this properly. Edit your question so that we can review it.

Comment: A note on terminology. With "parameter generation" we generally talk about (domain) parameters that are identical for all the key pairs generated using the key pair generation algorithm (usually just identified as $\text{Gen}$). In this case you just generate the keys themselves not so much the parameters as RSA doesn't require any - maybe the key size and often the public exponent, as mentioned. For elliptic curves the parameters are the parameters that define the curve (usually represented using a name or OID - a named curve).